# Automate logging into PuTTY and running commands

Tags: command-line, batch-file, putty

I regularly login to PuTTY and run the following commands to complete a task.

1st Command :

> cd/u01/app/oracle/user_projects/domains/COLLECT/EOD/bin_arm

2nd Command :

> ./FileUpload.sh

3rd Command :

> cd/u01/app/oracle/user_projects/domains/COLLECT/EOD/bin_arm

4th Command :

> ./execute_eodarx.sh

How can I automate this with the help of batch or other scripting?

I need to run these commands synchronously. (The next command is to run after the completion of the previous command.)

Answer (score 1):

You practically wrote the script already. If you put all four commands in a file on the server, then you can run it via `sh myscript.sh` and you have the batch script.

(If you also want it to be runnable as `./myscript.sh`, first add the `#!/bin/sh` header at the top, then use `chmod a+x myscript.sh` to mark the file as executable.)

Comment: thanks for your comments guys, @grawity, can i run this commands serially in windows environment e.g put all the commands in a batch file and run it with the help of Windows task scheduler to automate the process?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any Windows OS , try using [Multi Tabbed Puty](http://ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/)

It has features like save and manage putty sessions and automatically run scripts whenever the sessions are started.

To run commands automatically after logging in ,

- Right click on your Putty Session from Servers and select Properties
- Click on Scripts tab in the newly opened dialog box
- In the box provided, you can add the commands which will be run after
  login
  You can also specify the wait period too after which the commands will be executed.

Comment: Irrespective of platform. If you use tmux you don't need Multi tabbed Putty, since it can do tab. It can also split the screen